# Facebook like button renders slowly - cache available?

Tags: django, facebook-like

I managed to add FB like button on my twitter-bootstrap navbar using django-like-button
application.

Now my concern is that the like button renders after my page has already been fully loaded.
I'm using the same button (same href) on each page.

I was thinking if there is an option to cache the button and have it only render once.

I'm open to hear other options that may load it faster.
I'm using the async sdk from Facebook already.

10x

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724994/how-can-i-make-facebook-like-buttons-faster

Comment: As I said, I'm already using the async JS.
i don't want to render the like button on every page just wanted to render it once and cache it for other pages since they all share the same button.

Comment: I switched to sharethis.
does anyone know how to make the facebook like popup to be opened on top and not on bottom? 
i am using the button on my footer.